# what classical PDEs have analytical expressions for soliton-like shape solutions but motionless?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

what classical PDEs have analytical expressions for soliton-like shape solutions but motionless?

for example, KdV has analytical expressions of the kind (sech^2(x-vt)), but all of them are propagative, and introduce a drift to cancel its motion is not an option.

I am looking for a classical PDE with a straightforward and well known unimodal (or one bump-like) analytical solutions, but motionless.

Comment: The object you're interested in is usually dubbed "standing wave". Any google search will help you. Quite a few examples are known on metric graphs (e.g.: NLS, Dirac).

Comment: Yes, I found a lot of nonlinear models with standing waves as solutions, but with analytical solutions are few. Nevertheless, NLS is maybe the most closer to my needs. Thanks @DelioMugnolo